# what it means to have a flag disputed?

Tags: support, questions, flagging

In my profile, in flags history. What it means when you flag an answer or a question and the flag has the state disputed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [conversation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag) on Meta Stack Overflow:

> A disputed flag is a flag that was issued on a post that then received
>   an "invalid flag" flag from a 10K+ user. Both the original flag and
>   the flag used to mark it as invalid will be listed as "disputed" in
>   the respective user's flagging summary. Once a flag has been disputed,
>   its state will not be changed by any additional action on the post.

Comment: I also find this one to be useful...thanks so much http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112392/am-i-using-the-invalid-flag-flag-wrongly

Comment: To add to what said from MPD, once a flag is disputed, not even a moderator can mark it as helpful, even if the flag was for a question to close, and the question is closed.